# Equivalent for the Persian idiom "Khaste Nabaashid"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

We Persian speakers have a common idiom, **Khaste Nabaashid**, and usually say it to someone who finished a task or is in the middle of doing that. 
The literal translation of the idiom is something like *don't be tired* or *I hope you do not feel tired*.

Most of time non-Persian speakers who learnt Farsi become confused when we say them **Khaste Nabaashid**. So, I think there is no equivalent for that in other languages, specifically English.

Is there any idiom that conveys this?

**Update:**
I just read somewhere, the equivalents may be *nice job* or *well done*! However, I'm not OK with them.

**Update 2:**
As a given scenario, it could be used as greeting! When we see a friend who's doing some work, we usually say, Salaam (Hello), Khaste Nabaashid!

Moreover, if she/he is doing something for us, the idiom conveys our appreciation, otherwise it's used as some type of admiration.

**Update 3:**
This expression implicitly signals the end of the work. For example, when students are tired and want to indirectly and politely ask the teacher to stop and end the course, they usually use this expression and tell him/her *Khaste Nabashid!*

Comment: *It's all downhill from here.*

Comment: Going by the answers so far, people are not quite sure what you are talking about. Little wonder, as you have not really explained the phrase at all. You only provided a literal translation, which is always of little help, and especially when we're looking at an idiom. Please explain *why* this phrase is used, by whom, to whom, and *to what end*. So far you've only said you can say it to someone who finished a task or hasn't finished a task. That applies to absolutely anyone at all times ever, and covers all situations, real or imaginary. Certainly you can be more precise than that. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, Thanks for the comment, I've just added more info about the idiom's meaning and usage.

Comment: Just so you are aware, some cultural things don't translate easily or follow all the constraints of the original situation. For example, the German '[Mahlzeit!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahlzeit)' means literally 'Meal time!' but really isn't an announcement that you are going to a meal (even though it is usually in that context). You just don't say that in English, it would be weird. So it may (or may not) turn out similarly for your phrase. You really need to describe more of the nuances, the feelings of the situation, and even then there may not be a corresponding understanding.

Comment: @Mitch, Agreed, and I mentioned in OP that I think there is no exact equivalent for that. However, I was wondering if there is something close to that.

Comment: Khaste=Tired,being, Na= no, dont, baashid=be 
I hope you dont feel tired

Comment: @rabarkareem, Thanks for that, however this is the literal translation and could not convey the message.

Comment: This is a duplicate of  'A sentence for a person who is greatly tired'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, As I mentioned in OP and comments, only it's literal definition is equal with what you said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A sentence for a person who is greatly tired](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72078/a-sentence-for-a-person-who-is-greatly-tired) 'Keep up the good work' and 'Hang in there' are given as answers in the duplicate.

Comment: Hi @Eilia are you able to explain why the duplicate, suggested above, isn't suitable? What is missing from phrases such as 'you're doing a great job', or 'keep up the good work'? Does the phrase you're seeking need to refer to how tired the person is? Does it also need to be able to act as a general greeting, eg 'hi!'? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify the sense of it, the response is usually "khayli mamnoon" (thank you very much). The phrase is both encouraging and empathetic.

Comment: @Theresa, Of course, "kheili mamnoon" is more appropriate!

Comment: The correct answer is that there's no equivalent. I'd suggest making it into an idiom by simply saying: don't be [too] tired [dear].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three, often ironical or derisory([source brainy-quote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/good_job.html)),

> 'Good job, awesome, well done,'

but this song from '*Life of Brian*' would show that I really meant it.

> Always look on the bright side of life.

Comment: This does not seem like a relevant answer to the question.

Comment: +1, for "Well done". I just saw a photograph that confirmed this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

**Keep up the good work** is a common expression which sounds like it has a similar meaning ([reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Keep+up+the+good+work)).

But it might carry more weight than the Persian phrase does.  You'd usually only say it to encourage someone - for example if they seemed dispirited, or to signal that you understood they were performing a difficult task.  In more neutral situations, you'd just say something like **good job** or (in very informal speech) **nice one**.

Answer (score 6):

**[Keep on trucking](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=keep%20on%20trucking)** (UD)

> general phrase of encouragement meaning to stay focused on a particular job or in general.
>
> "you're doing a great job, keep on trucking."

---

In some contexts, "What doesn't kill you makes you stronger" could be used.

---

Then we have [this classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_Calm_and_Carry_On):

### [image]

EDIT: (Strictly opinion) After learning more about your context, I think the best fit here would be these:

- Carry on
- [Keep at it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Keep+at+it!)

These words can be encouraging, or mocking; depending on the context. (We have a similar expression in India. When we have to translate it, we use 'Carry on'.)

- You pass someone by, who seems busy. 'Hi. Carry on.' can be a greeting.
- You're done for the day, while your collegue seems stuck. Saying 'Carry on' in the right tone can convey smugness.
- And of course, 'Carry on' can simply be said to encourage someone.

Comment: "Keep on trucking" sounds like a much better fit than quoting Nietzche...

Comment: @Eilia: "Don't stop now" is fairly common. Does that work for you? Unfortunately, I can't find any references.

Comment: @TusharRaj, Unfortunately it doesn't work in this case and even may convey a negative implication. :)

Comment: @Eilia: Oh. Right. Could you please give me some more details of your context?

Comment: @  ExOttoyuhr Nietzche worked for the British Ministry of Information?

Comment: @TusharRaj, It's a bit complicated since this idiom is used in different ways, even for humiliation! As another scenario, it could be used as greeting! When we see a friend who's doing some work, we usually say, **Salaam** (Hello), _Khaste Nabaashid_!

Comment: @Eilia: I get it now. See edit.

Comment: Nietzsche was kidding.

Comment: @J.R.: Thanks for the edit. Any way I can specify height when adding an image?

Comment: @TusharRaj - I only know of two ways: (a) select a smaller image to begin with, or (b) open the image on your local machine, resize it, save it to a local file, and upload the modified image.

Comment: @TusharRaj, Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure that _Carry on_ is the exact equivalent, however it seems to be so close.

Answer (score 5):

**Hang in there** or **Hang on** seem to have a close approximation.

This is typically said when the task at hand is tiresome or requires extra effort. It is also usually said with a degree of sympathy and motivation.

Comment: This is the one that can be modified to work as a greeting.  "Still hanging in there, man?"  "Yeah, another day, another dollar."  That would be at the beginning of a conversation, or it could be the entire conversation.  As a conversation closer, Daniel's "Hang in there" would work well, as would some of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

**See the light at the end of the tunnel** is a phrase that is used to recognize that one is near the end of a task or has completed a significant task that makes any later tasks seem easy to accomplish.

The "light" is the goal one is trying to reach (to get out of the tunnel, complete the task). Once you have the light in sight, the hard work or most of the task is done.

An ironic parallel phrase is *the light you see at the end of the tunnel is an oncoming train.* This has the exact opposite meaning of the one above. It means the task is going to become significantly more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase that sprang into my mind? **Keep on keeping on**.

[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+on+keeping+on) lists it as an idiomatic expression, defining it as:

> **Keep on keeping on** - keep trying; keep doing what you are doing

The phrase is catchy enough to have appeared in [several musical titles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_On_Keeping_On#See_also), and it encourages the listener to [persist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/keep+on+keeping+on) in their toil.

Answer (score 2):

**[Buck up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buck%20up)** can be used as a form of encouragement.

> "Buck up, you're almost halfway through reviewing those documents."

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of phrases that could fit this, but I wonder if there is any sentiment behind the Persian phrase that denotes sympathy with a situation, which might lead one to use,

> keep going, you're almost there

Or if it is just a motivator similar to,

> Suck it up

...which can be heard on athletic fields across the United States.

Answer (score 0):

To express a genuine concern that your co-worker is working too late or just “do[ing] too much of something”, especially if the work is for your benefit, you could say “[don’t overdo it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/overdo+it)," either by itself or as part of a greeting (The Free Dictionary/Idioms)

Just in case the Persian phrase is ever used sarcastically or ironically, you could use “[don’t knock yourself out/don’t overexert yourself](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_knock_yourself_out)” in those situations. (Wiktionary)